# Use a class from Class Library and use it to be the Base Class of other Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I'm trying to practice inheritance of OOP. I have 2 Class Libraries. First is "BaseClass" and the second one is "DerivedClass". In the BaseClass library I have a Person class. In the DerivedClass library I have a Student class. I want to use the the Person class to be the base class of Student but I cant. I already add a reference to the DerivedClass but still it did not worked. How to do it? Or is it possible to use a class from other class library to be a base class of a class of other class library?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BaseClass
{
    class Person
    {
        public String Firstname { get; set; }
        public String Middlename { get; set; }
        public String Surname { get; set; }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BaseClass.Person;

namespace DerivedClass
{
    class Student
    {
         public int StudentID {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To inherit from another class use this notation: `class Student : Person {...}`.

And probably you will have to mark base class as public.

```
class Student : Person {...}
public class Person {...}
```

Comment: I include the public on Person. It's now okay. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please mark it as an answer to this topic. Thank you.